# Ubuntu 14.04 Requested size ** exceeds 3D hardware limit ** - dual monitors

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, resolution

I know this has been discussed before, but the solutions I found is for older versions of Ubuntu. What about the 14.04?

Any idea on setting up two monitors to work with Ubuntu Unity decently? Not interested on GNOME or other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I used ARandR.

```
$ sudo apt-get install arandr
$ arandr
```

Worked like a charm

Comment: I have the same issue as above ... and also installed arandr ... but what do I need to do next or what adjustments do I have to take?